# How to calculate offset of 4 hours and 30 minutes within function worldClockZone

Tags: javascript, function, offset

I want to calculate below code with 4 hours and 30 minutes to GMT but I have no idea to add 30 minutes in this code, can anyone help me?

```
    function worldClockZone(){
document.getElementById("Dehli").innerHTML = worldClock(4, "India")
```

While Dehli is City, 4 is the time offset (which I need to 04:30 instead) and India is region.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using the following code:

https://www.proglogic.com/code/javascript/time/worldclock.php

The code seems to match, so I'll give it a go as it's generic enough and might be of use to others as well. As is, the function `worldClock` does not support this behaviour. However, you could do some tinkering. Add the following:

```
// handle float
var remainder = Math.floor( ( zone % 1 ) * 60 )
zone = Math.floor( zone )
```

before adding the zone parameter to `hr`:

```
var hr = gmtTime.getHours() + zone
var min = gmtTime.getMinutes()
var sec = gmtTime.getSeconds()
```

afterwards handling the remaining minutes:

```
// make sure to adjust hr and min accordingly
min += Math.abs( remainder )
hr += ( remainder != 0 && min >= 60 ? 1 : 0 )
min %= 60
```

and then call:

```
function worldClockZone(){
document.getElementById("Dehli").innerHTML = worldClock(4.5, "India")
```

This should work for all float numbers, including negatives.

Comment: Nice, this is working not only for 30 minutes offset, but also for 15 minutes or 45 minutes offsets. for this, you need to put 0.25 for 15 minutes & 0.75 for 45 minutes offset